# Lego Boost: how can I gain access to all the programming blocks?

Tags: boost

I've just started playing with Lego Boost. Currently I only have very few programming blocks available in the Android app. According to [this](https://legoboost.blogger.de/), I should be able to unlock all blocks by pressing the symbol with the three bricks. But this symbol doesn't exist in my version of the app.

Does anyone know how to unlock all the blocks? Or can anyone recommend using an older version of the app that does allow you to unlock all the blocks?

Comment: What version do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the link provided by @RSchulz, this is my current understanding of programming blocks availability in the Lego Boost app:

There are two different types of canvas areas in which you can create projects: the Coding Canvas which you can reach by tapping on the big red toolbox that is in each robot submenu, and the Creative Canvas, which can be reached from the main menu by tapping on the open window.

The former has different blocks for each robot, and gets blocks added every time you complete one of the predefined tasks.

The latter has many advanced blocks but is missing robot-specific blocks that are in the other canvases.

There is no canvas that makes all existing blocks available.

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, and according to [this review on Tom's Guide](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/lego-boost,review-4538.html), "As you navigate through the Boost program, you need to complete the simplest levels within each robot section before you can unlock the more complicated ones."

So perhaps you just need to keep using it? Or have you unlocked everything your version of the app has available?

Comment: Yeah, I would even say "should"

Comment: n00b question: what's the correct way to do this? Paste my comment into my question? Mark RSchulz' answer as accepted answer? Write a new answer myself that sumarizes RSchulz' answer and my comment?

Comment: If your answer is better, don't mark mine as best! But otherwise, they all sound good.

Answer (score 1):

To unlock any level in Boost app: press and hold the padlock. It will open after 5 seconds. Have fun!